# Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL pool - IIF statement is not working

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

Trying to use **IIF()** in SELECT statement and getting the error "***Incorrect syntax near '>'***." in ***Azure Synapse Analytics-Dedicated SQL pool***

Tried like below:

```
SELECT IIF(1>2, 'YES', 'NO');
```

[image]

This error makes me to believe that IIF statement is not working at all in Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool.

Knew that, **CASE** is alternative but want to know Is there any specific reason behind this non-working of IIF in Synapse Dedicated SQL pool?

Any know-how or knowledge share would be much appreciated regarding this!

Comment: It's clearly identified that this operator is not supported by Synapse analytics: "IIF is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool." => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: `CASE` is standard SQL.  `IIF()` is bespoke SQL.  I would suggest that you use the method that is standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaime Drq mentioned in comment, ***At this point of time, IIF is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool*** and **this is at feedback/discussion level alone**.

So requested the same in discussions of Tech community of Microsoft. Hopes Azure Synapse Analytics team will implement this simple add-on in nearby future.

If you also want this to be in Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool, let the community to know this thing and give your likes at Tech community of Microsoft -
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/azure-synapse-analytics-dedicated-sql-pool-iif-statement-support/m-p/2659481#M16

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), IIF is not supported in dedicated SQL pools at this time.  The equivalent of your statement using a CASE statement is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 2 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END;
```

`IIF` **is** currently by serverless SQL pools:

[image: IIF on serverless]